# Passing Results from one React JS Function To Another React JS Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-data-api

I am trying to access the returned data from the 'getServerSideProps' function from the Home function to display the result, but I've had zero luck. Is anyone able to provide any suggestions?

To be as clear as possible, getServerSideProps() looks for a list of videos in a specified playlist, and I am trying to pass the data to the home function to display the result. I had to remove export from getServerSideProps(); otherwise, the function would console.log an undefined response.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Home.css'
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';
//Repositories
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const YouTube_Playlist_Items_API = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Item_API_URL;
const YouTube_Key = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_API_KEY;
const YouTube_Playlist_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Item_ID;
const YouTube_MaxResults = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Max_Results;

const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${YouTube_Playlist_Items_API}?part=snippet&playlistId=${YouTube_Playlist_ID}&maxResults=${YouTube_MaxResults}&key=${YouTube_Key}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log('data', data);
    return {
        props: {
          data
        }
    }
}

const Home = () => {
    getServerSideProps();
    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <div className='homeBody'>
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Check this: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects

Comment: I tried that and it did not return the actual data.

Comment: Please paste the code with use effect

Comment: I saw where I went wrong using useState. I referenced https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useState was the resolution to my issue.

```
    // declare useState data
    const [YTData, setYTData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    //Declare the async data fetching function
    const getServerSideProps = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        //Get the data from the api
        fetch(`${YouTube_Playlist_Items_API}?part=snippet&playlistId=${YouTube_Playlist_ID}&maxResults=${YouTube_MaxResults}&key=${YouTube_Key}`)
        //Convert data to json
        .then((res) =>  res.json())
        .then((data) => {
        setYTData(data.items);
        setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getServerSideProps();
    }, []);
```

Return block:

```
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <div className='homeBody'>
                {isLoading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : YTData.map((obj) => <p>{obj.snippet.title}</p>)}
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
```